# Tried to create a procedure which returned an incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to execute the following statement, when I got an incorrect syntax error:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GoogleMap]
( 
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [CityName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,  
    [Latitude] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,  
    [Longitude] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,  
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_GoogleMap] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  
) ON [PRIMARY]  
GO  
  
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddNewLocation]  
    (@CityName nvarchar(50),  
     @Latitude numeric(18, 0),  
     @Longitude numeric(18, 0),  
     @Description nvarchar(100))  
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[GoogleMap] (CityName, Latitude, Longitude, Description)  
    VALUES (@CityName, @Latitude, @Longitude, @Description)  
END
  
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMap]  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CityName, Latitude, Longitude, Description 
    FROM [dbo].[GoogleMap]  
END
```

The error points to line 15

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMap]
```

I'm still a newbie, so I'm not quite sure what mistakes I have done here.

Comment: Try putting a semi-colon at the end of the previous procedure and add a `go`.

Comment: A `CREATE PROCEDURE` (and `ALTER`) can be the **only** statement in the batch. Separate them into separate batches and you won't get an error.

Comment: add GO at the end of first proc

Answer (score 1):

Put the go after each create table and procedure. You will not get that error again

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GoogleMap]
( 
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [CityName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,  
    [Latitude] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,  
    [Longitude] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,  
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL,  

    CONSTRAINT [PK_GoogleMap] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]  
) ON [PRIMARY]  

GO
  
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddNewLocation]  
    (@CityName nvarchar(50),  
     @Latitude numeric(18, 0),  
     @Longitude numeric(18, 0),  
     @Description nvarchar(100))  
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[GoogleMap] (CityName, Latitude, Longitude, Description)  
    VALUES (@CityName, @Latitude, @Longitude, @Description) ; 
END
go
  
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMap]  
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT CityName, Latitude, Longitude, Description 
    FROM [dbo].[GoogleMap]  
END
go
```